# Как разместит маленький div в большой div с текстом?

Tags: html

кто поможет с div-ом. Есть большой div с текстом, нужна в этот же div разместить маленький div по правому? Пример в прикрепленной картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Разместите тег этого дива до начала соответствующего абзаца и задайте ему css-свойство `float: right`

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Nam condimentum sagittis scelerisque. Curabitur dapibus nulla metus. Duis aliquam nibh quis metus iaculis, eu ornare orci porttitor. Vestibulum tempus nibh non orci malesuada, quis pharetra neque ultrices. Curabitur eget consectetur metus, at consectetur nisl. Sed vehicula justo sit amet tortor accumsan, sed interdum urna vulputate. Vestibulum ultricies sed purus in efficitur.</p>

<div>Pellentesque sed velit nec diam ultrices faucibus. Aliquam sed pulvinar risus.</div>

<p>Ut dui nibh, laoreet et nibh in, venenatis bibendum metus. Praesent condimentum nisi in elit condimentum eleifend. Donec vestibulum purus sit amet nisl ornare tempus. In ornare diam ut lectus convallis fermentum.</p>

<p>Fusce tortor dui, sodales eu luctus eget, varius ut sapien. Pellentesque non felis sagittis, accumsan risus eget, vulputate nunc. Etiam molestie odio in dolor bibendum, sit amet volutpat erat sodales. Sed arcu neque, egestas non luctus vel, cursus a enim. Cras vel ante eu leo aliquet gravida. Proin auctor neque eu dui hendrerit, feugiat mattis nunc vehicula. Pellentesque sed velit nec diam ultrices faucibus. Aliquam sed pulvinar risus. Proin commodo libero placerat orci commodo, vel tincidunt tellus iaculis. Maecenas volutpat, ligula tincidunt rutrum dapibus, dui eros ornare odio, facilisis volutpat ex mauris sit amet massa.</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное Павел) Получилась)